# Distinguishable particles/atoms in classical and quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, identical-particles

**Classical Mechanics** It is often said that the particles/atoms in classical mechanics are distinguishable because we can keep track of their trace. First how is this possible? If we have 3 atoms how can we know which is which? First we can close our eyes and then someone interchange their position. When opened them up we don't know which is which. Second there is no analytical solution for 3 or more  bodies so we can't know their trajectories.

**Quantum Mechanics** Are only particles (or also atoms) considered indistinguishable in QM? Reading forums the most frequent answer is that for two particles like electrons when they are very close we can't know which is which because their wavefunctions overlap. So the indistinguishability depends on how close are the particles or is something more fundamental?

I would be grateful for an conceptual/intuitive answer.

Answer (score 3):

Before getting to your questions, let me first point out a (potentially obvious) difference. The question of distinguishability that is usually present in physics refers to whether two objects are distinguishable or not *given a physical context*.

For example, imagine I tell you I have two identical pens and I'm thinking about one of them. Now, I ask you, about which one am I thinking? Your answer to this question, as well as the question itself, are meaningless. This is because since the pens are identical you have no way to refer to any of them. In this sense, any two identical particles (or objects in general) are indistinguishable.

However, imagine now I show you my two identical pens placed on a desk and ask you to do the same thing. You can, in this case, point towards the pen you believe I am thinking about. Although the pens are still identical, you can distinguish between them because they are put in a physical context, i.e. lying on a desk, and they have different spatial coordinates (which is by what you distinguish them). This is the sense in which we discuss about distinguishability in physics, and I will only consider this sense in what follows.

In **classical mechanics**, indeed we can distinguish between any two particles because we can keep track of their trajectories. We can, for example, distinguish them because they will have different spatial coordinates. Once we saw them, we can label them in our mind as particle $1$ and particle $2$ and if we observe them closely we can follow their trajectory and at any point later in time still know which is particle $1$ and which is particle $2$.

This is a way of keeping track of their trajectories, however, we don't need to do that. Before I detail a more mathematical way of thinking about keeping track of trajectories, let me first address your second question about the non-existence of analytical solutions for $3$ or more body systems.

The fact that analytical solutions don't exist all the time doesn't mean we can't follow the trajectories of the particles. In fact, it is only important to note that the theory of differential equations assures us that Newton's equations of motion always have a solution and that this solution is unique. Whether or not we can find this solution, the particles will always follow a deterministic trajectory given appropriate initial conditions. If there is no analytic solution, we can, for example, observe them (as mentioned above) to keep track of their trajectories. Alternatively, we could also try to find numerical solutions. Regardless of how we do it, the only important thing is that there always exists a unique trajectory for each particle given the appropriate initial conditions, so in principle we can always follow their trajectories.

Therefore, mathematically speaking, what we need is to be able to write down the equations of motion and specify initial conditions, i.e. the positions and velocities of the particles at a given time. Once we did this, the future (as well as the past) of the system is completely determined by the solution to this system of differential equations (which as mentioned before it always exists and is unique), so we can in principle distinguish the particles by following their trajectories at any point in time.

In the example you gave where apparently we can't distinguish between two classical particles,

> If we have 3 atoms how can we know which is which? First we can close our eyes and then someone interchange their position. When opened them up we don't know which is which

we are not keeping track of the trajectories of the particles. We obviously don't watch them closely, and if we were to solve Newton's equations of motion we should include the external force the other person exerts on each particle to swap them, but we don't include this external force because we don't know it's there (if we did know this force was there, i.e. if we did know that someone swapped the particles, we would be able to distinguish the particles because we kept track of their trajectories while being swapped).

When it comes to **quantum mechanics**, the situation is a bit different. To answer your first question, any identical objects in quantum mechanics are indistinguishable, but quantum mechanical effects are more easily seen experimentally in very small objects, so we usually talk about the distinguishability of particles.

It wouldn't be right to say that indistinguishability depends on how close two particles are. Instead, indistinguishability is better thought of as a property of identical particles. On the other hand, how close two particles are can influence "how well can one distinguish between indistinguishable particles."

To make sense of this "statement," it's important to note the difference between Newton's equations in classical mechanics and (the time-dependent) Schrodinger's equation for quantum mechanics. While by solving Newton's equations one finds the **trajectories** of the particles, by solving Schrodinger's equation one can only calculate the **probability** of finding the particles at some position in space at a given time.

Hence, by solving Schrodinger's equation one can find something like: at a given time, there is a probability $a$ for the particles to be in positions, say, $1$ and $2$, respectively, and there is a probability $b$ for the particles to be in positions, $2$ and $1$, respectively. It is, thus, clear that if $a$ and $b$ are nonzero then either scenario is possible, and the two physical situations are indistinguishable (as the particles are identical).

However, I've mentioned before that how close two particles are can influence "how well can one distinguish between them." In general, if particles are very far apart, their wavefunctions have very small amplitudes where they overlap. Say, for example, that one particle has a very high probability to be on Earth while a second particle has a very high probability to be on the Moon. In such a scenario, the wavefunctions would have very small amplitudes in the region of overlapping. So, if we detected a particle to be on Earth and the other particle to be on the Moon, it is very likely that if we find a particle at a later time somewhere around Earth that this particle is the initial particle we found on Earth.